# Outlook 2010 VBA script deployment

Tags: vba, deployment, outlook, outlook-2010

I wrote a VBA script for Outlook 2010. The purpose of this script is to clean some elements from the tasks and contacts for the user. This needs to be done following a migration to a new client managing solution. Since Exchange is connected to the new solution some items are doubled so we need to delete the items from outlook. Ideally this would be done on the Exchange server but we don't have access to it directly...

My script is already working but my problem lies with the distribution of said script. We don't have direct access to the computers of these people so what we need is a way to package it in a download, have them run it once from a link in an email and forget about it. Most of these users have about zero computer knowledge. Ideally I don't want this script to remain in Outlook after that one execution.

I searched for a solution but found nothing...

Here's my script if that helps. Also, I'm not a good programmer... So if there's a better way to do this don't hesitate to tell me.

```
Private Sub CleanUp()
Dim TaskFolder As Folder
Set TaskFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
Dim Task As TaskItem
Dim objProperty As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim uProperty As String
Dim collTasks As New Collection

Dim ContactFolder As Folder
Set ContactFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Dim Contact As ContactItem
Dim objPropertyCLS As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim uPropertyCLS As String
Dim collContacts As New Collection

uProperty = "crmxml"
uPropertyCLS = "crmLinkState"

For Each Task In TaskFolder.Items
    Set objProperty = Task.UserProperties.Find(uProperty, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
    If objProperty Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "objProperty is Nothing"
    ElseIf InStr(objProperty, "phonecall") > 0 Then
            collTasks.Add Task
    ElseIf InStr(objProperty, "letter") > 0 Then
        collTasks.Add Task
    ElseIf InStr(objProperty, "fax") > 0 Then
        collTasks.Add Task
    End If
Next

For Each Contact In ContactFolder.Items
    Set objPropertyCLS = Contact.UserProperties.Find(uPropertyCLS, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olNumber)

    If objPropertyCLS Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "objPropertyCLS is Nothing"
    ElseIf Not objPropertyCLS Is Nothing Then
        collContacts.Add Contact
    End If
Next

For Each Task In collTasks
    Task.Delete
Next

For Each Contact In collContacts
    Contact.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *So if there's a better way to do this don't hesitate to tell me.* - that's what [codereview.se] is for, have you tried yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA scripts were not designed for deploying them on multiple PCs. If you need to run your code on multiple PCs you have to develop an add-in instead. Add-ins can be installed by users easily like any other Windows programs. If the add-in is not required any longer, it can be un-installed or disabled from the COM add-ins dialog in Outlook. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly.